# How to update the sum of selected option elements on change

Tags: php, jquery, html, select, onchange

I'm trying to understand why the sum is not being updated.

This is my drop-down list:

```
echo "<select name='CPU'>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if($row['id']==1)
        echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'a='" . $row['productprice'] 
       . "'>" . $row['productname'] . "</option>";
    else if($row['productstock']>0 && $row['id']>1)
        echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'a='" . $row['productprice'] 
       . "' >" . $row['productname'] . " Price:" . $row['productprice'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

And this is my function to update the sum:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var sum = 0;
    $('select :selected').each(function() {
        sum += Number($(this).attr("a"));
    });
    $("#sum").html(sum);
    //
});
```

Comment: Update function seems to be javascript, not php.

Comment: This `$('select :selected')` won't select the option

Comment: The sum of what? Can you select multiple "CPU" or do you have other `select`?

Comment: i have 9 other select that work like the select here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each call of

```
$('select').change(function(){
```

you are initializing again `var sum = 0;` and that's the reason it is not getting added to previous value. You need to take out the initialization and initialize only once when page load.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var sum = 0;
   $('select').change(function(){
      $('select :selected').each(function() {
         sum += Number($(this).attr("a"));
      });
   $("#sum").html(sum);
   })
});
```

**[>>>Demo<<<](https://jsfiddle.net/pwsu1gf9/)**